# Как можно достать данные с базы данных с расширением .16

Tags: c#, c++, sql, база-данных, firebird

мне нужна помощь на предприятии используется старая программа для начисления оплаты за услуги (некоторые файлы с датой изменения 1998 год) она использует firebird odbc версии 2. База данных обновляется раз в месяц путем простой подмены файла ZKP.16 файл размером 4.67Gb (в интернет ничего не смог найти по расширению .16 и не знаю чем его открыть). Добрые люди посоветовали открыть файл бинарным редактором (картинка №2) ничего внятного кроме проскакивающих фамилий клиентов этот способ не подсказал. Прошу еще какие небудь мысли как достать все данные из этого файлика в нем должны храниться данные ФИО адрес, начислено, оплачено и т.п.

P.s. еще в папке sql есть файлик zkp.sql скрин начала файла прилагаю.

[image: zkp.sql]
[image: Файлы в папке программы]
[image: база открыта в HxD редакторе]

Comment: Есть вероятность что используется MS SQL Server

Comment: я так понял, этот файл используется для обновления БД? По идее это может быть что угодно, я бы предположил какой то свой бинарный формат для передачи между базами данных. Но у вас есть exe файлики рядом, поробуйте их открыть и глянуть, что они делают и как читают этот файл.

Comment: Попробуйте натравить линуксовую команду `file` на файл, может она его идентифицирует.

Comment: Покажите первые строки в hex/бинарным редакторе. Заголовок формата обычно там.